# How to use a function in two different classes with different return parameters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I had the following snippet:

```
class one(xyz):
    def __init__(self,...):
    ....
    def myfunction(self,p,q):
        ....
        self.dummy_ = 1
        self.corr_ = 3
        return self
class two(one):
....
class three(one):
```

Here, I want `myfunction()` to return only `self.corr_` and not `self.dummy_` in `class two` but want all of `self.dummy_` and `self.corr_` to be returned in `class three`.
One way to achieve this is to write the same function in both the classes after removing the function from the base class. But is there a way to achieve this task without taking `myfunction()` out of the `class one`.

Comment: You're returning `self`, meaning the entire object, not just those specific values. Does or doesn't your object contain the `dummy_` property? If it's not supposed to contain it, maybe you shouldn't be inheriting a class that does in the first place.

Comment: In addition to @deceze answer, have a look at abstract classes

Comment: I am at first inheriting from `xyz` which does not have `dummy_` and `corr_`, I am defining it inside the function and then returning the whole object. Am I missing something?

Comment: `xyz` doesn't matter much at all. You're inheriting from a class (`one`) which *does* define those attributes. So `two` and `three` should exhibit them as well.

Comment: So, this is what I want to ask, is there a way I can modify the code in `one` so that this `self.dummy_` is inherited in `three` but not `two`.

Comment: That would require `one` to have knowledge of its child classes, which is a general no-no. You would simply have to override `myfunction` in `two` if you want it to behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
class one(xyz):
    def __init__(self,...):
    ....
    def myfunction(self,p,q):
        ....
        self.dummy_ = 1
        self.corr_ = 3
        return self

class two(one):
    def myfunction(self,p,q):
        ....
        return self.corr

class three(one):
    ....
```

It's called method overriding. You can override a method that you inherited and thereby give a specific subclass a different implementation of that method.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#Python

Comment: Will it work if there are more than 2 parameters in self variables in `class one` , and we want to return all but one? 
Example if there's one more variable `self.third` and we want `myfunction()` in `class two` to return two self variables and `myfunction()` in `class three` to return all self variables.